# xCode: How to sort a collection view with long press?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, collectionview

I have a scroll view now. It has 2 images in each row. I wanna to add long press sorting for this view but I think its better to replace this scroll view with a collection view for easier sorting. I didn't find anything to learn how to sort a collection view with long press. I want users be able to long press each image and move it for sorting the images.

Appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` for doing this. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/moveItemAtIndexPath%3atoIndexPath%3a) is the doc link. You just need to add a gesture recognizer to each cell and and call the method after you do the drop of the view.

You might want to write code to get the index path of source cell and destination cell though before calling the above method.

Also look towards the end of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html) doc page.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It sounds really good. Don't you have any sample codes of this?

Comment: Not yet. When I get some free time I'll try to create something. You work on it in parallel in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me so much.